# Dev Cpp shows wrong percentage in this cpp program

Tags: c++

What I have tried

- I tried to make percentage static

**I don't understand why this percentage variable in setData displays wrong value**

I made percentage variable public. But that's allowed in cpp.
**Program description**

This is a very simple program. I was doing it to learn how we can define function outside class.

**Expected Output**

```
 If marks in subject 1 -> 10 (max 100)
    subject 2 -> 10

    subject 3 -> 10

    subject 4 -> 10

    subject 5 -> 10

    Total -> 50

    percentage -> 10 %
```

**`Source code`**

```
#include<iostream>
    using namespace std ;
    class result{
      char name[30];
      int a,b,c,d,e;
    public:
      int total;
      double percentage;
      int rollno;
      int subjects;
      int sum(){
        int total;
        total=a+b+c+d+e;
        return 0;
      }
      void setdata();
      void getdata();
    };
    void result::setdata(){
      cout<<"enter the name of the student"<<endl;
      cin>>name;
      cout<<"enter the rollno of the student"<<endl;
      cin>>rollno;
      cout<<"marks in english:"<<endl;
      cin>>a;
      cout<<"marks in hindi:"<<endl;
      cin>>b;
      cout<<"marks in maths:"<<endl;
      cin>>c;
      cout<<"marks in science:"<<endl;
      cin>>d;
      cout<<"marks in social studies:"<<endl;
      cin>>e;
      percentage=(total/500)*100;
      if (percentage<35.5){
        cout<<"!!!!!!FAIL!!!!!!"<<endl;
      }else(cout<<"!!!!!!PASS!!!!!!"<<endl);
    }
    void result::getdata(){
      cout<<"name of student is:"<<name<<endl;
      cout<<"the roll number is:"<<rollno<<endl;
      cout<<"the number of subjects are:"<<subjects<<endl;
      cout<<"marks in english is: "<<a<<endl;
      cout<<"marks in hindi is: "<<b<<endl;
      cout<<"marks in maths is: "<<c<<endl;
      cout<<"marks in science is: "<<d<<endl;
      cout<<"marks in social studies is: "<<e<<endl;
      cout<<"total marks of all subjects :"<<total<<endl;
      cout<<"the total pecentage of "<<name<<" is: "<<percentage<<endl;
    }
    int main(){
      result abhishek;
      abhishek.subjects=05;
      abhishek.setdata();
      abhishek.getdata();
      return 0;
    }
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x98fU.png)

Comment: Please show text info as text, not as picture of text.

Comment: wild guess: `percentage=(total/500)*100;` thats an integer division. make it `500.0`

Comment: What output do you get? What would be the expected output? Can you describe the difference?

Comment: I changed the 500 to 500.0 but answer is still abrupt number @Raildex

Comment: @Yunnosch I have tried to add a expected result. I don't understand your comment `Please show text info as text, not as picture of text. `

Comment: @Jack you never call `result::sum()` and thus, `total` is never set. There are more issues with your code. I'll write that in an answer

Comment: Thanks for adding info to the question. You show a link to a picture of text. I recommend to instead show the textual info in the picture directly as a text quote in your question. For similar reasons like https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: You have a member variable `int total`, but in the `sum()` member function you have a local variable `int total`. The local variable is **hiding** the member variable.

Comment: Compile your code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` to get all warnings and debug info. Improve your code to get no warnings. Perhaps use the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) on your C++ code, if allowed to. Use the [GDB debugger](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) to understand the behavior of your executable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems.

```
percentage=(total/500)*100;
```

This line accesses `total`. However, you never set `total` to a value. It is uninitialized and will contain garbage value if you try to access it.

- You have a function `int result::sum()` which calculates `total`, you
  have to call it before you calculate `percentage`. `class Result`
  also has a member `total`, but in your `sum()` method you create a
  new `total`. I don't know what your intended use is. I'd say you
  should calculate `result::total`
- `sum()` also returns an `int` but you return a `0` and calculate
  `total`. Change the function to return `void` instead.
- I'd also suggest to use a floating point division instead of an
  integer division: `percentage=(total/500.0)*100;`
- Change `result abhishek;` to `result abhishek{}` to zero-initialize
  all members of `result` to avoid garbage values.

Here's a revamped version of your code:
https://godbolt.org/z/r4ase1

Comment: It worked like a charm!. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to resorting to float for calculating percentage would be to write:

```
percentage=total/5;
```

Integer division suffices if you don't need precision beyond whole numbers. So 0.2% will become 0 percent and 25.1% will become 25%.

Also drop the habit of `using namespace std`. [why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1):

The problems of the code are as follows.

1- You do not call sum() function before calculation (or anywhere else), so the total has a garbage value at the beginning instead of total of the points.

2- sum() call returns an int, it should return void.

3- Integer division on almost all languages returns the floor value of the mathematical result instead of real result, C++ is one of those languages.

Instead of dividing numbers in raw form, you should cast everything to either float or double.

Here is a better, working version of your code. Also reformatted your code a little bit, so that it is easier to read.

```
#include<iostream>

    using namespace std ;
    
    class Result{
        char name[30];
        int a,b,c,d,e;
        public:
            int total;
            double percentage;
            int rollno;
            int subjects;
            void sum(){
                total=a+b+c+d+e;
            }
            void setdata();
            void getdata();
    };

    void Result::setdata(){  // Capitalized first letter
        cout<<"enter the name of the student"<<endl;
        cin>>name;
        cout<<"enter the rollno of the student"<<endl;
        cin>>rollno;
        cout<<"marks in english:"<<endl;
        cin>>a;
        cout<<"marks in hindi:"<<endl;
        cin>>b;
        cout<<"marks in maths:"<<endl;
        cin>>c;
        cout<<"marks in science:"<<endl;
        cin>>d;
        cout<<"marks in social studies:"<<endl;
        cin>>e;
        sum();  // calling sum
        percentage=((float)total/5.0)*1.0;   // Used 5 and 1 instead of 500 and 100, converted numbers to float
        if (percentage<35.5){
            cout<<"!!!!!!FAIL!!!!!!"<<endl;
        }else{
            cout<<"!!!!!!PASS!!!!!!"<<endl
        };
    }
    void Result::getdata(){
        cout<<"name of student is:"<<name<<endl;
        cout<<"the roll number is:"<<rollno<<endl;
        cout<<"the number of subjects are:"<<subjects<<endl;
        cout<<"marks in english is: "<<a<<endl;
        cout<<"marks in hindi is: "<<b<<endl;
        cout<<"marks in maths is: "<<c<<endl;
        cout<<"marks in science is: "<<d<<endl;
        cout<<"marks in social studies is: "<<e<<endl;
        cout<<"total marks of all subjects :"<<total<<endl;
        cout<<"the total pecentage of "<<name<<" is: "<<percentage<<endl;
    }
    int main(){
        Result abhishek;
        abhishek.subjects=05;
        abhishek.setdata();
        abhishek.getdata();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The is still hiding the member variable `total` by the local variable `total` in the `sum()` member function.